# post a strange form using httpclient

Tags: html, vb.net, post

I've been googling for quit some time and i can't find a good answer. Im using httpclient to post a very strange form,it has no method attribute and the child elements has no name attribute. the form looks like this:

```
<form action="#" novalidate="" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-12="12">
    <div data-components="pdr-signin-form" id="ember13" class="ember-view">
    <div data-components="pdr-signin-id" id="ember14" class="ember-view">
    <div data-components="pdr-text-field" id="ember15" class="ember-view"><div>
        <div class="textfield-input-wrapper">
            <input dir="ltr" autocomplete="on" title="Sign-In ID (Email Address)" tabindex="2" placeholder="Sign-In ID (Email Address)" maxlength="63" id="ember16" class="textfield ember-text-field ember-view" type="email">
        </div>
        <!----></div>
        <!----></div>
    </div>
    <div data-components="pdr-password-input" id="ember17" class="ember-view">
    <div data-components="pdr-text-field-v2" id="password" class="ember-view"><div>
        <div class="textfield-input-wrapper">
            <input dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" title="Password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30" id="ember18" class="textfield ember-text-field ember-view" type="password">
        </div>

    </div>
    <!----></div>
    <button tabindex="2" title="Password Display Off" class="icon-disp-password disp-icon-off" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-19="19">
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the code im using:

```
Async Function DownloadPageAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Dim page As String = "myurl"
    Dim values As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"ember16", "nathantodd7@yahoo.com"}, {"ember18", "nathantodd7@yahoo.com"}}
    Dim content As Object = New FormUrlEncodedContent(values)

    Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()

        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(page)
            Using contents As HttpContent = response.Content
                ' Get contents of page as a String.
                Dim result As String = Await contents.ReadAsStringAsync()
                Return result

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```